# mitmweb My saved flows do not appear when opened?

Tags: mitmproxy

So I just recorded some requests and then saved the flows.

I closed mitmweb, reopened it, and then opened the saved flows.

But there are no requests that appear?  The saved flows file is 100MB.

Answer (score 0):

You need to dump it:

```
from mitmproxy import io, http
from mitmproxy.exceptions import FlowReadException
import pprint
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], "rb") as logfile:
    freader = io.FlowReader(logfile)
    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
    try:
        for f in freader.stream():
            print(f)
            if isinstance(f, http.HTTPFlow):
                print(f.request.host)
            pp.pprint(f.get_state())
            print("")
    except FlowReadException as e:
        print(f"Flow file corrupted: {e}")
```

I have not found a way to reopen